# How to optimize this query which taking long time.?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

While working with following query on mysql, Its taking to execute around 10sec.

```
   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT
          b.appearance_id,
          b.photo_album_id,
          b.eventcmmnt_id,
          b.id,
          b.mem_id,
          b.subj, 
          b.body,
          b.image_link as photo_image_uploaded,
          b.bottle_id,
          b.date, 
          b.parentid, 
          b.from_id, 
          b.visible_to,
          pa.photo_big as image_link,
          b.post_via,
          b.youtubeLink,
          b.link_image,
          b.link_url,
          b.auto_genrate_text,
          badges.badge_img,
          badges.badge_bottle_img,
          b.type,b.share_url_title
     FROM bulletin b 
          INNER JOIN network n 
                     ON (n.mem_id = b.mem_id) 
          LEFT JOIN badges 
                     ON (b.bottle_id=badges.badge_id) 
          LEFT JOIN photo_album as pa 
                    ON (pa.photo_id=b.photo_album_id) 
          JOIN members mem
                    ON (b.mem_id=mem.mem_id and mem.deleted<>'Y') 
    WHERE b.parentid = '0'
          AND ('$userid' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id,b.from_id)) 
 GROUP BY b.id 
 ORDER BY b.id DESC 
    LIMIT 0,10
```

The Inner query inside IN constraint has many `frd_id,mem_id,from_id` So I think because of that above query is executing slowly... So please help to optimize above query

Thanks

Comment: try using mysql's `explain plan`

Comment: wow this is one hell of a sql query.

Comment: nobody knows your schema or indexes

Answer (score 0):

Check, that you have indexes on fields, which are used for joins.

Comment: this is not an answer, should be in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already been hinted, post the `EXPLAIN SELECT...` plan for the query. Why guess when you can check? (And a SQL Fiddle would be great too).

That will tell whether you need indexes (very, very likely!) and which indexes and how structured (*do not* go and index everything, since this may even harm performances!).

One suggestion I can already give: if you have an index field on `members` of the form

```
(mem_id, deleted, ...)
```

as you should, verify that `deleted` is indeed a `boolean` (if it is not, convert it to an `enum` of 'Y' and 'N'), and specify the condition like this:

```
on(b.mem_id=mem.mem_id AND NOT mem.deleted)
```

since this will go much easier on the indexing. If the field is *not* boolean, for example it may have the values 'Y', 'N' and 'P' for 'Pending', and you used a `varchar` field, then the `<>` has a considerable performance impact on the index - I'd even go out on a limb and say that the index is effectively neutralized. Indexes work best with *matches*, not with *non-matches* as `<>`.

I suspect you can also re-engineer this expression

```
AND ('$userid' IN (n.frd_id, b.mem_id,b.from_id))
```

by moving it, albeit partially, in the `b` `JOIN`. Or you could consider, depending on your tables' cardinality, using a `UNION` instead.

Comment: thanks isemi, i need to change IN query to exist clouse, so can you tell me how can i do?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your meaning. What is it that you need to do? Can you supply an example?